# remove alpha characters and white space from string

Tags: c#, .net

I have a string which contains many characters.  I want to remove A-Za-z and white space and be left with the rest.  What's the best way to do this?

Here's what I've tried

```
presaleEstimateHigh = Regex.Replace(presaleEstimateHigh, @"[A-Za-z]", string.Empty);
```

but I also need to remove white space.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use \s.

For example:

```
presaleEstimateHigh = Regex.Replace(presaleEstimateHigh, @"[A-Za-z\s]", string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your regular expression is fine, except for the whitespace. This should work:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[a-zA-Z\s]+", string.Empty);
```

Comment: `%20` is not the only whitespace in town.

Answer (score 3):

Without regular expressions:

```
var chars = str.Where(c => !char.IsLetter(c) && !char.IsWhitespace(c)).ToArray();
var rest = new string(chars);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\s` to include whitespace.

```
Regex.Replace(myString, @"[a-z]|[A-Z]|\s", "")
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/yHG2xw

Answer (score 1):

You almost made it. Use this regex expression

```
[a-zA-Z ]+
```

It simply includes the whitespace. Adding a `+` makes it more efficient, as whole series of characters can be replaced at once (internally).

Comment: This doesn't include tabs though.